# Labels of a tree

Tags: list, haskell, tree

With the following data type

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

I would like to create the following function:

```
labels:: Tree a -> [a]
labels (Node label children) = label: (map labels children)
```

but this fals as

```
   * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
      Expected type: [a]
        Actual type: [[a]]
```

Having children as x:xs didnt help either as xs would still be a list of trees and not a single tree.

Comment: I assume the type is supposed to be `data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]` with `a` in place of the unspecified type variable `label`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `labels` has type `Tree a -> [a]`. This thus means that if you construct a `map labels`, it has type `map labels :: [Tree a] -> [[a]]`. You thus need to concatenate these items, such that we produce a list `[a]` instead of `[[a]]`.

You can use [**`concatMap :: Foldable f => (a -> [b]) -> f a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) instead:

```
labels :: Tree a -> [a]
labels (Node label children) = label : concatMap labels children
```

> Having `children` as `x:xs` didnt help either as `xs` would still be a list of trees and not a single tree.

Indeed, furthermore by using `(x:xs)` you will (unnecessary) restrict yourself to trees with a non-empty list of children. It is a common misconception that `x` and `xs` are "special" variable names in `(x:xs)`. You just pattern match on the "cons" data constructor `(:)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `join` to convert `[[a]]` to `[a]`, which comes from monad laws.

For example:

```
module Tree where

import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Control.Monad (join)

data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a] deriving stock Show

makeBaseFunctor ''Tree

labels :: Tree a -> [a]
labels = cata $ \case
  TreeF a y -> a : join y
```